# How do I authorize a client with Kerberos in a .net api in docker?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, kerberos

I have a .net minimal api thats running in a docker container on a linux server. Its configured to use Kerberos authentication. I have created an SPN, keytab and krb5.conf file. The keytab seems to work fine when using klist and kinit.

The endpoint in my api is:
`app.MapGet("/GetUsernameLinux", [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Negotiate")] (HttpRequest req) => {}`

All my endpoint seem to fail on the [Authorize} portion and i get a 500 error in my docker logs. Here is the error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler[5]
      An exception occurred while processing the authentication request.
      System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: GenericFailure
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HN0MO6K60DUR", Request id "0HN0MO6K60DUR:00000006": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: GenericFailure
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

What am i doing wrong?

I have tried the endpoint locally and it works over IIS express. It only seems to fail once i dockerize the api on linux.

Here is the rest of my code:

```
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "/bin/bash",
    Arguments = "-c \"kinit -k -t /etc/krb5.keytab svc@domain\"",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true,
};

using var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
var error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

process.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine($"Output: {output}");
Console.WriteLine($"Error: {error}");
Console.WriteLine($"Exit code: {process.ExitCode}");

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate(options =>
    {
        options.Events = new NegotiateEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticated = context =>
            {
                var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.Principal.Identity.Name));
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

// Add authorization services
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<EOMContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

// Add CORS services
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://server:port")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Hello.  I have never done Kerberos in Linux.  I am fully unaware if .Net can even do this in Linux, even if Linux itself provides a Kerberos implementation.  Do you have evidence that is even possible?  I would be interested in reading about it.  Traditionally, I would say "You cannot do this in Kubernetes/Docker because pods can spin up or die and Kerberos requires the server to be joined to the domain, which requires a stable name, which is something pods don't have".